# Make page act like 404

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, screenshot

I want to make a page act like if it isn't exists and print out a 404 error message. This works perfectly but the page it self is showing under the whole website when the 404 page is visible.

Code:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found', true, 404);
require_once('error.php');
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Does anyone here know how I can fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found', true, 404);
require_once('error.php');
exit ();
```